# Javascript \x escaping

Tags: javascript, string, escaping, ascii, processing

I've seen a few other programs that have something like this:

```
var string = '\x32\x20\x60\x78\x6e\x7a\x9c\x89';
```

And I had to try to fiddle with the numbers and letters, to find the text I wanted to display.
I'm wondering if there is a function to find the `\x` escape of a string, like `string.toUpperCase()` in JS. I'm using [processing](/questions/tagged/processing)JS, but it will be okay for me to use other programming languages to find the ASCII for `\x`.

Comment: Those programs could (and should) just have used ```var string = '2 `xnz\x9c\x89';```, and nothing would have been different.

Comment: That is true, But I wasn't used to this until now, I usually just type the characters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have a string that you want escaped, you can use [`String.prototype.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)

If you have the code with escapes, you can just evaluate them to get the original string.  If it's a string with literal escapes, you can use [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

- If you have `'\x32\x20\x60\x78\x6e\x7a\x9c\x89'` and want `` "2 `xnz" `` then

  ```
    '\x32\x20\x60\x78\x6e\x7a\x9c\x89' == "2 `xnz"
  ```
- If you have `'\\x32\\x20\\x60\\x78\\x6e\\x7a\\x9c\\x89'` which is a literal string with the value `\x32\x20\x60\x78\x6e\x7a\x9c\x89` then you can parse it by passing the decimal value of each pair of hex digits to `String.prototype.fromCharCode()`

  ```
    '\\x32\\x20\\x60\\x78\\x6e\\x7a\\x9c\\x89'.replace(/\\x([0-9a-f]{2})/ig, function(_, pair) {
      return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(pair, 16));
    })
  ```

  Alternatively, `eval` is an option if you can be sure of the safety of the input and performance isn't important<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/198031/1059070)</sup>.

  ```
    eval('"\\x32\\x20\\x60\\x78\\x6e\\x7a\\x9c\\x89"')
  ```

  <sup>Note the `"` nested in the `'` surrounding the input string.</sup>

  If you know it's a program, and it's from a trusted source, you can `eval` the string directly, which won't give you the ASCII, but will execute the program itself.

  ```
    eval('\\x32\\x20\\x60\\x78\\x6e\\x7a\\x9c\\x89')
  ```

  <sup>Note that the input you provided is not a program and the eval call fails.</sup>
- If you have `` "2 `xnz" `` and want `'\x32\x20\x60\x78\x6e\x7a\x9c\x89'` then

  ```
    "2 `xnz".split('').map(function(e) {
      return '\\x' + e.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
    }).join('')
  ```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out.