# Convert hexified js file into text

Tags: javascript

I have a large file and I want to understand what is going on there.
However, it seems like file is encoded.
Piece of content from it:

`var _0x36ba=["\x69\x73\x41\x72\x72\x61\x79","\x63\x61\x6C\x6C","\x74\x6F\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67","\x70\x72\x6F\x74\x6F\x74\x79\x70\x65","\x5B\x6F\x62\x6A\x65\x63\x74\x20\x41\x72\x72\x61\x79\x5D","\x74\x72\x69\x6D","","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x76\x69\x65\x77\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x53\x69\x7A\x65","\x67\x65\x74\x48\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74","\x48\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74","\x67\x65\x74\x57\x69\x64\x74\x68","\x57\x69\x64\x74\x68","\x74\x6F\x4C\x6F\x77\x65\x72\x43\x61\x73\x65","\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72","\x63\x6C\x69\x65\x6E\x74","\x62\x6F\x64\x79","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x69\x64","\x76\x70\x77\x2D\x74\x65\x73\x74\x2D\x62","\x63\x73\x73\x54\x65\x78\x74","\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65","\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x66\x6C\x6F\x77\x3A\x73\x63\x72\x6F\x6C\x6C","\x64\x69\x76","\x76\x70\x77\x2D\x74\x65\x73\x74\x2D\x64","\x70\x6F\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x3A\x61\x62\x73\x6F\x6C\x75\x74\x65\x3B\x74\x6F\x70\x3A\x2D\x31\x30\x30\x30\x70\x78","\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C"];`

This is hex. For example, `\x69\x73\x41\x72\x72\x61\x79` is `inArray`. How can I convert all the file into readable text?

Comment: Paste it into an online decoder - do a search for "hex to text" on Google.

Comment: similar to [javascript \x escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34056509/javascript-x-escaping), it looks like you can use [String.fromCharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

Comment: They don't work. As text is not pure hex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try a simple `.toString` with a forEach loop.

```js
var _0x36ba=["\x69\x73\x41\x72\x72\x61\x79","\x63\x61\x6C\x6C","\x74\x6F\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67","\x70\x72\x6F\x74\x6F\x74\x79\x70\x65","\x5B\x6F\x62\x6A\x65\x63\x74\x20\x41\x72\x72\x61\x79\x5D","\x74\x72\x69\x6D","","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x76\x69\x65\x77\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x53\x69\x7A\x65","\x67\x65\x74\x48\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74","\x48\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74","\x67\x65\x74\x57\x69\x64\x74\x68","\x57\x69\x64\x74\x68","\x74\x6F\x4C\x6F\x77\x65\x72\x43\x61\x73\x65","\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72","\x63\x6C\x69\x65\x6E\x74","\x62\x6F\x64\x79","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x69\x64","\x76\x70\x77\x2D\x74\x65\x73\x74\x2D\x62","\x63\x73\x73\x54\x65\x78\x74","\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65","\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x66\x6C\x6F\x77\x3A\x73\x63\x72\x6F\x6C\x6C","\x64\x69\x76","\x76\x70\x77\x2D\x74\x65\x73\x74\x2D\x64","\x70\x6F\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x3A\x61\x62\x73\x6F\x6C\x75\x74\x65\x3B\x74\x6F\x70\x3A\x2D\x31\x30\x30\x30\x70\x78","\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C"];

_0x36ba.forEach(function(item, index) {
  _0x36ba[index] = item.toString();
});

console.log(_0x36ba)
```