# Converting slashed utf8 string to latin-1 (ISO 8859-1) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, encode, iso-8859-1

I am receiving from backend the string `"something \xe9 something else"` and I would like to convert it to `"something é something else"`.

I've done some search on that and haven't found anyone else with this same problem, however I came up with the following that worked for me:

```
function decode(str){
    return eval('"' + str + '"');
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly this questions has nothing to do with UTF-8 or ISO 8859-1, you're simply trying to convert \x escape sequences in your strings back into the corresponding characters. Perhaps the answers here will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34056509/javascript-x-escaping

Comment: Like @skirtle, this is not a utf8 issue, instead of eval `JSON.parse('"something \xe9 something else"')` might be less resource hungry.